# Lambda function fails to instantiate when using AWS CDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, python-3.7, aws-cdk

I'm trying to use the AWS CDK to deploy a Lambda function that will be triggered by an S3 upload event. When I try doing `cdk ls` or `cdk synth`, I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 14, in <module>
    S3TosqsStack(app, "S3TosqsStack", env=core.Environment(account=os.getenv('CDK_DEFAULT_ACCOUNT'), region=os.getenv('CDK_DEFAULT_REGION')))
  File "/home/ec2-user/s3tosqs/.venv/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/jsii/_runtime.py", line 83, in __call__
    inst = super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ec2-user/s3tosqs/s3tosqs/s3tosqs_stack.py", line 37, in __init__
    bucket=s3.IBucket(bucket_name=lambda_deployment_bucket),
  File "/home/ec2-user/s3tosqs/.venv/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/typing_extensions.py", line 1548, in _no_init
    raise TypeError('Protocols cannot be instantiated')
TypeError: Protocols cannot be instantiated
Subprocess exited with error 1
```

It looks like the issue is stemming from the `bucket` definition for the lambda function, but I don't understand what the error is because I followed the documentation. I tried using `bucket_arn` instead of `bucket_name`, but that didn't work either.

Here is the main stack code:

**s3tosqs_stack.py**

```
from aws_cdk import (
    aws_s3 as s3,
    aws_s3_notifications as s3_notifications,
    aws_sqs as sqs,
    aws_lambda as _lambda
)

from aws_cdk import core

# User-specified Parameters
lambda_deployment_bucket = 'some-deployment-bucket'
trigger_bucket = 'some-trigger-bucket'
trigger_key = 'uploads'
queue_name = 'some-queue.fifo'
region = 'us-west-2'

class S3TosqsStack(core.Stack):

    def __init__(self, scope: core.Construct, construct_id: str, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(scope, construct_id, **kwargs)


        # Defines an SQS queue resource
        queue = sqs.Queue(
            self, 'NotificationQueue',
            queue_name=queue_name,
            content_based_deduplication=True,
            visibility_timeout=core.Duration.seconds(300)
        )

        # Defines an AWS Lambda resource
        lambda_function = _lambda.Function(
            self, 'S3toSQS',
            runtime=_lambda.Runtime.PYTHON_3_8,
            code=_lambda.Code.from_bucket(
                bucket=s3.IBucket(bucket_name=lambda_deployment_bucket),
                key='S3toSQS.zip'),
            handler='handler.publish_SQS_message',
            environment={'SOURCE_BUCKET': trigger_bucket,
                        'REGION': region,
                        'QUEUE_NAME': queue_name}
        )

        # Define S3 upload bucket for Lambda trigger
        upload_bucket = s3.Bucket(
            self, 'S3TriggerBucket',
            bucket_name=trigger_bucket
        )

        upload_bucket.add_event_notification(
            s3.EventType.OBJECT_CREATED,
            s3_notifications.LambdaDestination(lambda_function),
            s3.NotificationKeyFilter(
                prefix=trigger_key)
        )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using the bucket reference using the Bucket and from_bucket_name ?

```
        lambda_function = _lambda.Function(
        self, 'S3toSQS',
        runtime=_lambda.Runtime.PYTHON_3_8,
        code=_lambda.Code.from_bucket(
            bucket=s3.Bucket.from_bucket_name(self, "id",bucket_name=lambda_deployment_bucket),
            key='S3toSQS.zip'),
        handler='handler.publish_SQS_message',
        environment={'SOURCE_BUCKET': trigger_bucket,
                     'REGION': region,
                     'QUEUE_NAME': queue.queue_name}
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two probable causes for the issue you are experiencing.

1. Modify your code as shown below. The modification is on line 4, in the way the arguments to the "from_bucket" method is called.

```py
lambda_function = _lambda.Function(
            self, 'S3toSQS',
            runtime=_lambda.Runtime.PYTHON_3_8,
            code=_lambda.Code.from_bucket(s3.IBucket(bucket_name=lambda_deployment_bucket),'S3toSQS.zip'),
            handler='handler.publish_SQS_message',
            environment={'SOURCE_BUCKET': trigger_bucket,
                        'REGION': region,
                        'QUEUE_NAME': queue_name}
        )
```

2. You are using Python 3.7 to run your CDK code. As far as I know, that version of Python does not support Protocol typings hence the error. Try upgrading to Python 3.8